# How do I assign a xsd location in JaxB

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, jaxb, xsd

I'm using JaxB 2.2, can't use MOXy or other JaxB implementations due restrictions.
Is there a way to assign a created xsd to a Xml Element or Class in Eclipse? For example if I have an xsd in WebContent/validators/schemas and the file name is "foo.xsd" and I have a class in "foo.bar.classes" package named "foobar.java" with three fields "foo1" "foo2" "foo3". How do I assign the xsd to the class or the fields? I'm using @XMLElement and @XmlRootElement on that class. Thanks.